# Creating collection as union of multiple geometry

Tags: qgis, postgis

In my PostGIS database I have 2 geometries of type :
dot and multilinestring.

I need a third geometry of type geometry collection which is the union of the two geometries.

How do I create the collection even when I have more than one geometry: for example point, multilinestring and polygons?

Comment: You have two tables, one with points and one with lines? How should the tables be combined, by some common id?

Comment: I have a column of a table with geometry of type point and another column of the table with geometry of type multiline.
I need to combine the two columns and put the result of this combination into a collection.

Comment: So row1 in point table is combined with row1 in line table, row2 - row2, row3 - row3?

Comment: in column 1 I have point type geometry, in column 2 I have polygon type geometry, I will need a column 3 where I will have
a collection with the point of column 1, and the polygon of column 2. Eventually if I add other geometries, in the same way.